# SP Online Lazy approval using SPD 2013 or MS flow

Tags: designer-workflow, approval, flow

I'm trying to configure lazy approval in SharePoint Online site using SPD 2013 or using MS Flow. Is it possible? I couldn't find any documentation related to it.

By Lazy approval, I mean, when the approver receives the approval request email, he should just reply to the automated email as Approved or Rejected and his response should be tracked for approval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may create a simple Microsoft flow approval process. The approver gets to see Approve/Reject button directly in the email notification received.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with SPD2013 but it is far, far easier with Flow.

There is not a REST interface for SPD2013 workflows, so you would need to do it with JSOM, which makes it impractical if your desire is to include "Approve" and "Reject" buttons in an e-mail.

Flow does this very well, as mohd said: 
[image]

See Also: [Request manager approval for leave requests](https://us.flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/906bdcc238bb49f19879ab62a88f3aa7/request-manager-approval-for-leave-requests/)